# Website Deployment in IIS : IIS can't access directories?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-deployment, windows-server

[image: IIS Settings MySite : Connection Strings - Error!]

I did an Application in ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio 2019 in my local machine, then after deploying for my file system, I copied the files to the server. Meanwhile, I created a new IIS site on the server (Windows Server) indicating the settings that I want, including the use of https.

However, when I try to access the site an error occurs, and apparently the IIS can't access the program folder…

When I try to navigate in the website settings in IIS and click to see the connection strings, the IIS gives me the error in the picture. In fact, it seems that there are a problem with the path. What does it mean `\\?\C:\mydir\web.config` ?

Anyone could give me help on how to solve this error? I am sure that I indicated the correct path to IIS.

Comment: You forgot to install ASP.NET Core module on IIS. That's it.

Comment: could you please share your web.config file? if you are using url rewrite rule make sure that you installed the iis url rewrite Extention. and also check that you installed the asp.net feature of iis. ensure that  .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle has been installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already installed the .NET Hosting Bundle and the above problem was solved.
However, now, I continue to not be able to access the website I created. The browser gives error `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`.

Here is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\MVF2.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 99f7528d-8954-427a-86a5-7124668717df-->
```

The Program.cs file is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MVF2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 8088, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        listenOptions.UseHttps("mycertificate.crt");
                    });
                });
    }
}
```